# Kernel panic rebooting - Xenserver Tools

Tags: server, xen

Topic edited, see revs for more information.

I've an Ubuntu Server 14.04 running on AWS that reboots every 5 minutes. I found this message when  accessing the console's panel:
[image: kernel panic]
[image]

I'm now trying to log Kernel Panic.

Comment: use kill -9 or pkill pid at os level to kill the suspected processid

Comment: What does `top` tell you?

Comment: @NawazSohail - kill proccess by proccess?

Comment: @terdon top returns low mem usage, i'll update the post

Comment: You can sort by memory usage (should be enough to press `>` when `top` is running) and then see what process is using all your ram.

Comment: @terdon yes, but, the memory usage before 5 minutes is fine, when server uptime takes 5 minutes, it restarts.

Comment: OK, but if you watch this for 5 minutes, you should be able to spot what's taking the memory. Alternatively, run this command: `while :; do ps -a -o %mem=,comm=,pid= | sort -rnk1 | head -n1 >> memory.log; sleep 1; done`. That will run `ps` every second and save the name, pid and mem percentage of the process using the most memory at that moment. Check the `memory.log` file to see which one was the issue and report back.

Comment: @terdon you're right, before the server restarts the process mysqld takes 100% of mem. I stopped and killed all proccess about it and waiting for the 5min restarts.

Comment: Not solved, The server has restarted and now, the top of memory usage is 3.3% www-data proccess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49598/discussion-between-terdon-and-luis-fedrizze).